# chart.js d3js chart in time scale, data from CSV file

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js, chart.js

first, thanks a lot for all the help from stackoverflow.

I'm trying to display charts which have Data spreaded according to the amount of time between data points. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html

so: X Axis: ---2022-02-01-----------2022-02-05-----------2022-02-07----------

My object:

X Axis: ---2022-02-01-----------2022-02-03-----------2022-02-04-----------

but the challenge is that the datas are not coming from the HTML code with x and y like this:

```
data: [{
    x: '2022-02-01',
    y: 25
}, {
    x: '2022-02-05',
    y: -25
}, {
    x: '2022-02-07',
    y: -225
}]
```

but from a CSV file.

So i don't know how to set the xAxis scale config with time.

Please somebody know how to solve it?

Thanks a lot.

```
     <script>


  d3.csv("example.csv").then(makeChart);

  function makeChart(players) {
    var dateData = players.map(function (d) {
      return d.date;
    });
    var btcData = players.map(function (d) {
      return d.btc;
    });
    var VETData = players.map(function (d) {
      return d.vet;
    });
    var totalData = players.map(function (d) {
      return d.total;
    });
    var BTCColors = players.map(function(d) {
        return d.btc < 0 ? '#F15F36' : '#19A0AA';
    });
    var VETColors = players.map(function(d) {
        return d.vet < 0 ? '#F15F36' : '#19A0AA';
    });
    var TOTALColors = players.map(function(d) {
        return d.total < 0 ? '#F15F36' : '#19A0AA';
    });


    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: dateData,
        datasets: [{
            type: 'bar',
            label: 'BTCUSDT',
            borderColor: BTCColors,
            backgroundColor:BTCColors,
            data: btcData
          }, {
            type: 'bar',
            label: 'VETUSDT',
            data: VETData,
            borderColor: VETColors,
            backgroundColor: VETColors
          }, {
            type: 'line',
            label: 'TOTAL',
            data: totalData,
            borderColor: '#F15F36',
            backgroundColor: '#19A0AA',
            borderWidth : 1,
            pointRadius : 1.1,
            fill:false
          }]
      }
    }
    );

    
    const config = {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: data,
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'time',
                    time:{
                        unit:'day'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
  };
</script>
```

js src:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"
  integrity="sha512-d9xgZrVZpmmQlfonhQUvTR7lMPtO7NkZMkA0ABN3PHCbKA5nqylQ/yWlFAyY6hYgdF1Qh6nYiuADWwKB4C2WSw=="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

my csv file:

```
date,btc,vet,total
2022-02-01,25,0,25
2022-02-05,0,-50,-25
2022-02-07,-200,0,-225
2022-02-20,-0,100,-125
2022-03-01,0,150,25
2022-03-15,400,0,425
2022-04-01,-100,0,325
2022-04-15,0,-10,315
2022-06-01,500,0,815
2022-07-01,0,200,1015
```

[chart preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U604r.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay i find the answer, had to convert the CSV into Arrays, and arrays into data structure:

```
<script>

      drawChart();
      async function drawChart(){
        const dataArray = await getData();
        const BTCdatapoints = dataArray.DATEdata.map((day,index) => {
          let dayObject = {};
          dayObject.x = dataArray.DATEdata[index];
          dayObject.y = dataArray.BTCdata[index];
          return dayObject
        })
        const VETdatapoints = dataArray.DATEdata.map((day,index) => {
          let dayObject = {};
          dayObject.x = dataArray.DATEdata[index];
          dayObject.y = dataArray.VETdata[index];
          return dayObject
        })

        const TOTALdatapoints = dataArray.DATEdata.map((day,index) => {
          let dayObject = {};
          dayObject.x = dataArray.DATEdata[index];
          dayObject.y = dataArray.TOTALData[index];
          return dayObject
        })

        const data = {datasets: [{
                  label: 'BTCUSDT',
                  data: BTCdatapoints
                  }, {
                  type: 'bar',
                  label: 'VETUSDT',
                  data: VETdatapoints
                }, {
                  type: 'line',
                  label: 'TOTAL',
                  data: TOTALdatapoints
                }]
            }

            const config = {
              type: 'bar',
              data,
              options: {
                scales: {
                  x: {
                    type: "time",
                    time: {
                      unit: "day"
                      }
                  },
                  y:{
                    beginAtZero : true
                  }
                }
              }
          };

          const myChart = new Chart(
            document.getElementById("myChart"),
            config
          );
        };

        async function getData() {
          const DATEdata = [];
          const BTCdata = [];
          const VETdata = [];
          const TOTALData = [];
          const url ='example.csv';
          const response = await fetch(url);
          const tabledata = await response.text();
          const table = tabledata.split('\r\n').splice(1);
          table.forEach(row =>{
            const column = row.split(',');
            const date = column[0];
            const BTC = column[1];
            const VET = column[2];
            const TOTAL = column[3];
            DATEdata.push(date);
            BTCdata.push(BTC);
            VETdata.push(VET);
            TOTALData.push(TOTAL);
          });         
          return {DATEdata,BTCdata,VETdata,TOTALData};
        }

    </script>
```

JS SRC:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/papaparse@5.3.2/papaparse.min.js"></script>
```